# Golang GIN - REST API - database is locked error

Tags: sqlite, rest, go

I am currently building a RESTFUL api with gin, golang, and sqlite3
i have a problem with database is locked error when executing multiple sql in one function other than that it work flawlessly

this is my route in main
`r.POST("/:database/:table/:replicate", AuthMiddleware(), createData)`

this is my  main function of createData

```
func createData(c *gin.Context){
    // Get the database name from the URL
    database := c.Param("database")
    table := c.Param("table")
    replicate, _ := strconv.ParseBool(c.Param("replicate"))

    // Parse the request body
    var data Data
    if err := c.BindJSON(&data); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err})
        return
    }

    // Get the database connection
    db_data, err := getDatabaseConnection(database)
    db := db_data.DB
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Failed to get database connection"})
        return
    }
    // dbMutex.Lock()
    // defer dbMutex.Unlock()
    
    //check if id exist
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT id,value FROM "+table+" WHERE id=?")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    rows, _ := stmt.Query(data.Id)
    var data_db Data
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&data_db.Id, &data_db.Value)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
    rows.Close()
    if data_db.Id  != ""{
        c.JSON(http.StatusConflict, gin.H{"error": "Id already exists"})
        return
    }

    // prepare SQL
    insert_stmt, err_insert := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO "+table+" (id,value) values (?,?)")
    if err_insert != nil {
        log.Println(err_insert)
    }

    // execute SQL
    _, errExec := insert_stmt.Exec(data.Id,data.Value)
    if errExec != nil {
        log.Println(errExec)
    }
    // if no error
    log.Println("Data Added Succesfully with Id %s", data.Id)
    jsonB, errMarshal := json.Marshal(data)
    if errMarshal != nil {
        log.Println(errMarshal)
    }
    if replicate {
        replicateData(data,database,table)
    }
    c.String(http.StatusOK, string(jsonB))
}
```

the problem is when executing replicate data to another when i want to save a data to a temporary db when other server cannot be accessed. the one that i labelled as "HERE IS THE PROBLEM"

```
func replicateData(data Data, dest_db string, dest_table string) {
    // Get the database connection
    db_data, err := getDatabaseConnection(os.Getenv("MAIN_DB"))
    db := db_data.DB
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to get database connection")
        return
    }
    // Query the database
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM "+os.Getenv("SYNC_TABLE_DB"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to query database")
        return
    }

    // read all data
    for rows.Next() {
        var server Sync_Server
        err = rows.Scan(&server.Server_Id,&server.URL, &server.Token, &server.Created_At, &server.Updated_At)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Failed to get sync server data")
            break
        }
        // run curl
        curl := fmt.Sprintf("http://%s/%s/%s/%s", server.URL, dest_db, dest_table,"false")
        log.Println("inserting data to : "+curl)
        
        // Marshal the JSON data into a byte array
        jsonData, err := json.Marshal(data)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        log.Println("jsondata")

        req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", curl, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to prepare request")
        }
        log.Println("request")

        req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        req.Header.Set("Token", "Octon168_")

        client := &http.Client{
            Timeout: 1 * time.Second,
        }

        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        log.Println("client")
        if err != nil {     
            // HERE IS THE PROBLEM (WHEN INSERTING TO TEMP)
            dbMutex.Lock()

            insert_stmt, err_insert := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO temp (data_id,sync_server_id,data_value) values (?,?,?)")
            if err_insert != nil {
                log.Println(err_insert)
            }
            _, errExec := insert_stmt.Exec(data.Id,server.Server_Id,data.Value)
            if errExec != nil {
                log.Println(errExec)
                log.Println("error insert")
            }

            dbMutex.Unlock()
            
            jsonB, errMarshal := json.Marshal(data)
            if errMarshal != nil {
                log.Println(errMarshal)
            }
            log.Println("Server failed to be reached, save in temp db %s", string(jsonB))
            continue
        }
        defer rows.Close()
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        log.Println("data with id: "+data.Id+" replicated to "+ string(body))
    }
}
```

i have tried mutex lock between the execute but it does not affect, still getting locked

- I have tried using mutex
- i have tried removing all mutex, this result in success first execute and locked the rest

UPDATE

- updating journal mode to WAL seems to have fixed the problem, but is there downside of enabling WAL? I am new in go and sqlite

Comment: Don't use `db.Prepare` if you're not going to reuse the statements. If you are going to reuse the statements then make sure to close them once you're finished with them.